# Write operations per second limit in firebase (for chat in a social app)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm developing this social networking app and I have used firebase for chatting feature.

While reading the firebase documentations they mention "1000 write operations/second" limit.

Isn't it too less?

For example for every message sent I write in 2 database nodes (for both users, receiver and sender) and then there are write operations for read receipts.

So that makes around 4-5 write operations per message sent.

I get the limit of 1000/5=200 users
So only 200 users can chat simultaneously in my app?

I may need to scale high, as the online users are expected to be around 10,000 at any moment and may be 1,000 of them are chatting.

So Firebase fails for my chat solution?

Answer (score 4):

Only 200 users can chat simultaneously in my app?

If you say that you'll have 10,000 users, there is small chance that 200 users will send a message in the same second. But if you reach the limit of 200 users that can chat in a single second, it means that your app is a very popular chat app and you'll need to think very seriously about getting a payed plan, `Flame Plan` or `Blaze Plan`.

Firebase won't fail your chat solution because technically can handle all your request but let's be serious, you cannot have a very popular chat app hosted on Firebase servers without paying a penny.

If you want to stay on the free plan, remember that when you'll reach the maximum number of writes per second, it doesn't mean that you'll not be able to use Firebase database anymore. When 1001th simultaneous connection occurs, a queue of operations is created and Firebase will wait until one connection is closed, and than it uses your new connection.

Comment: I already have the Blaze plan and the limit 1000 write ops/second is max of all plans. Also Simultaneous connection limit is 1,00,000.

Comment: I'm also aware of the fact that read operations doesn't have this limit

Comment: Thats's good. I can say then, you don't have nothing to worry about. Do you think my answer helped you in any way?

Comment: Yeah little satisfaction that I don't need to worry about it right now. I'll change the architecture in future